# Ionic 3: Displaying an ion-searchbar and ion-segment-buttons inline

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How does one display an `ion-searchbar` and an `ion-segment` inline in the same ion-toolbar? I'm using Ionic 3.

(in case you're curious, this is landscape-mode-only thing because in landscape mode vertical space is at a premium).

I'm (mostly) able to get this to work with `ion-col`, as seen below. Everything looks good in Chrome via Ionic Serve. But when running on a real device, the `ion-segment` gets pushed down and doesn't look right.

**Example code below:**

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col no-padding>
      <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="joined" (ionChange)="switchView($event)" color="light">
        <ion-segment-button [value]="true">
          {{'PROJECT_JOINED_BUTTON' | translate}}
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button [value]="false">
          {{'PROJECT_LIST_BUTTON' | translate}}
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col no-padding>
      <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="query" (ionInput)="load()" color="light" debounce="500" showCancelButton="true" placeholder="Search projects"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>


</ion-toolbar>
```

**How it looks in Chrome via Ionic Serve when spoofing iPhone mode**
[image: How it looks in Chrome via Ionic Serve when spoofing iPhone mode:]

**How it looks on a real iOS device:**
[image: How it looks on a real iOS device:]

**What works:**

I *am* able to get buttons to align to the end using `ion-buttons end`. However, when I wrap the `ion-segment` inside an `ion-buttons`, the segment doesn't appear at all. When I try applying the `end` attribute to the `ion-segment`, the segment overlays the search bar.

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">

  <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="query" (ionInput)="load()" color="light" debounce="500" showCancelButton="true" placeholder="Search projects"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button clear>
      Test Button
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>

</ion-toolbar>
```

[image]

Is there a way to reliably display an ion-segment inline with other content inside an ion-toolbar? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm have you tried specifying the col width explicitly like `col-4` and `col-8`? Sometimes this yields problems... Anyway try to [remote debug](https://moduscreate.com/blog/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/) on the device to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **align-items-center** and **col-6** like:

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row align-items-center>
        <ion-col no-padding col-6>
          <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="joined" (ionChange)="switchView($event)" color="light">
            <ion-segment-button [value]="true">
              {{'PROJECT_JOINED_BUTTON' | translate}}
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button [value]="false">
              {{'PROJECT_LIST_BUTTON' | translate}}
            </ion-segment-button>
          </ion-segment>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col no-padding col-6>
          <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="query" (ionInput)="load()" color="light" debounce="500" showCancelButton="true" placeholder="Search projects"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

**documentation:** https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/